# I want to play the selected mp3 file from Listview

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, baseadapter

I just want to play selected mp3 file from the list.getting the position of the onItemClick but no response from the listview.

Getting the mp3 files from SDCard.
Please Help me
Thanks in advance.

My Fragment

```
ListView lv_recordersList;
 private ListViewAdapter adapter;
 ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
 private List<String> myList;
 File file;


        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_recorders_list, null);
            lv_recordersList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_recordersList);

            myList = new ArrayList<String>();


            new DownloadJSON().execute();

        lv_recordersList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             String value = lv_recordersList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

             System.out.println("####### Value OnItemClick : " +value);

             try {
             mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(value);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
             } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });

            return v;
        }



    public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            //mProgressDialog.setTitle("PlugLeads");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            file = new File(directory + "/Plugleads");
            File list[] = file.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                // if(checkExtension( list[i].getName())
                if (checkExtension(list[i].getName())) {
                    myList.add(list[i].getName());
                }
            }


            return null;
        }




        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), myList);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            lv_recordersList.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }



        private boolean checkExtension(String fileName) {
            String ext = getFileExtension(fileName);
            if (ext == null)
                return false;
            try {
                if (SupportedFileFormat.valueOf(ext.toUpperCase()) != null) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public String getFileExtension(String fileName) {
            int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
            if (i > 0) {
                return fileName.substring(i + 1);
            } else
                return null;
        }


    }
```

My Custom BaseAdapter getView() :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ImageView img_recorders_listitem;
    TextView tv_recorders_listitem;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_recorders_listitem, parent, false);

    img_recorders_listitem = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_recorders_listitem);
    tv_recorders_listitem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_recorders_listitem);


    //resultp = data.get(position);
    System.out.println("$$$$$$$ ListP : " +myListp);

    pos = myListp.get(position);

    System.out.println("$$$$$$$ Pos : " +pos);


    tv_recorders_listitem.setText(pos);


    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();


    return itemView;
}
```

My Logcat

```
06-09 13:05:54.787: I/System.out(16669): ####### Value OnItemClick : gshsh_07-06-2016_12_11_17.mp3
06-09 13:05:54.803: W/System.err(16669): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
06-09 13:05:54.804: W/System.err(16669):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1086)
06-09 13:05:54.808: W/System.err(16669):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1032)
06-09 13:05:54.809: W/System.err(16669):    at com.plugleads.feedback.record.Frag_RecordersList$1.onItemClick(Frag_RecordersList.java:69)
06-09 13:05:54.809: W/System.err(16669):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
06-09 13:05:54.809: W/System.err(16669):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
06-09 13:05:54.809: W/System.err(16669):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
06-09 13:05:54.809: W/System.err(16669):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
06-09 13:05:54.809: W/System.err(16669):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-09 13:05:54.814: W/System.err(16669):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-09 13:05:54.814: W/System.err(16669):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-09 13:05:54.814: W/System.err(16669):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
06-09 13:05:54.814: W/System.err(16669):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-09 13:05:54.814: W/System.err(16669):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-09 13:05:54.814: W/System.err(16669):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
06-09 13:05:54.814: W/System.err(16669):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Please Help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: getting `Value OnItemClick :` in log?

Comment: No Response onItemClick.

Comment: Ok remove `itemView.setOnClickListener` from getView method then check

Comment: getting the value of OnItemClick what ever we select, I have added mediaplayer and setting the value to mediaplayer, but it is saying 06-09 13:05:54.803: W/System.err(16669): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
06-09 13:05:54.804: W/System.err(16669):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1086)
06-09 13:05:54.808: W/System.err(16669):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1032)
06-09 13:05:54.809: W/System.err(16669):  at com.plugleads.feedback.record.Frag_RecordersList$1.onItemClick(Frag_RecordersList.java:69)

Comment: @Naveen: show your updated code and error logs in question

Comment: i have edited.Please review the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in log:

```
IOException: setDataSource failed.
```

Because `gshsh_07-06-2016_12_11_17.mp3` is not valid file path for `MediaPlayer`.

Use full path including directory name in which file is currently available. like:

```
File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
file = new File(directory + "/Plugleads/"+ value);
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
```

Comment: hey how to show seekbar and stop options when listitem is clicked ?Please help me ASAP.Thanks in Advance...